# how to set different colors for different cells

Tags: objective-c, ios

How to set different colors to different calls? For example all cells with predicate "a" have red color, with predicate "b" - yellow, etc

Comment: and in what context (cells of an Html table ?)

Comment: UITableView with array of dates. If date is before current - cell color must be red, else - yellow. I need to set cells of different colours within one table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];

if (predicateA)
{
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
if (predicateB)
{
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
}
```

You can describe this colouring with the following truth table:

```
|    A     |     B    |    Color    |
-------------------------------------
|    1     |     1    |     YEL     |    <- What do you want here?
|    1     |     0    |     RED     |
|    0     |     1    |     YEL     |
|    0     |     0    |    UNDEF    |
```

However, I'm getting a little confused about what you want with the 1, 1 case

Comment: What outcome would you like `if (A && B)`?

Comment: Table contains NSArray, with different values. I want to set different colors for cells. All values with predicate A - have red color, all values with predicate B - have yellow colors

Comment: Is it possible to have BOTH predicates?

Comment: Sorry for my english, may be I can`t explain what i want ))
Look here http://pashich-ssd.ru/uploads/pictures/mb.jpg